# Hide table on mouseout using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a dynamic web page using Javascript, in which I am creating multiple tables with contents listed in each. Initially with `table 1` the page loads, When I mouseover on particular item on `table 1`, `table 2` is displayed next to `table 1` with a list of contents related to `table 2`. On `mouseout` the `table 2` should disappear.
This is done for each item in the list of `table 1`.

The problem I am facing here is, I am not able to align `table 2`, and on `mouseout` I am not able to vanish it.

please help.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\JS Projects\Net.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="myFunction()">
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS code:

```
function myFunction()
{
  document.body.style.background = "url('http://www.macwallhd.com/wp-content/Wallpapers/Animals/Desktop%20Cats%20As%20Hunters%20Pet%20Pictures10.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed"

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "wrapper";

  //Table Creation Start
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.id = "t1";
  table.style.cssText = "background-color:blue;color:White; padding:10px; opacity:0.3;margin-top:150px;display:block; position:absolute;align:center;width:250px;height:300px;";

  div.appendChild(table);

  var tr1 = table.insertRow(0);
  var td = tr1.insertCell(0);
  td.innerHTML = "favourites";

  var tr2 = table.insertRow(1);
  var td = tr2.insertCell(0);
  td.innerHTML = "system";

  var tr3 = table.insertRow(1);
  var td = tr3.insertCell(0);
  td.innerHTML = "settings";

  /***********Table creation End****/

  var table2 = document.createElement("table");
  table2.id = "t2";

  tr1.addEventListener("mouseover", createTable,false);

  tr1.addEventListener("mouseout", removeTable,false);

  document.body.appendChild(div);
  };

  function createTable()
  {
    //switch(choice)
    //{
    //    case: mouseover
    //        case: mouseout
    //}

    var div = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var table2 = document.createElement("table");
    table2.id = "t2";
    table2.style.cssText = "background-color:blue;color:White; padding:10px; opacity:0.3;align:center;width:250px;height:300px;margin-top:150px;margin-left:290px;display:block;";
    div.appendChild(table2);

    var tr1 = table2.insertRow(0);
    var td = tr1.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "channel 1";

    var tr2 = table2.insertRow(1);
    var td = tr2.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "channel 2";

    var tr3 = table2.insertRow(1);
    var td = tr3.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "channel 3";
  }

  function removeTable(){
    var elem = documenet.getElementById("t2");
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Aligning the table is a CSS problem, while the mouse event coordination a JS one. Which one are you asking?

Comment: You need to put a place holder for those tables if you want to organize everything

Comment: Just delete the `margin-top` property on the first table. Problem is css?

Comment: you have error in your removeTable() method documenet must be document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this : [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q98vy/)

1. Check whether table having id `t2` exist or not and then create a new one if does not exist.
2. And add `position:absolute` css to table2 having id `t2` also.

   ```
       function createTable()
           {

               var div = document.getElementById("wrapper");

                    if(document.getElementById("t2")) {
                       var table2 = document.getElementById("t2");
                       table2.style.display = 'block';
                       }
                    else {
                       var table2 = document.createElement("table");
                       table2.id = "t2";
                       table2.style.cssText = "background-color:blue;color:White; padding:10px; opacity:0.3;align:center;width:250px;height:300px;margin-top:150px;margin-left:290px;display:block;position:absolute";
                       div.appendChild(table2);

                       var tr1 = table2.insertRow(0);
                       var td = tr1.insertCell(0);
                       td.innerHTML = "channel 1";

                       var tr2 = table2.insertRow(1);
                       var td = tr2.insertCell(0);
                       td.innerHTML = "channel 2";

                       var tr3 = table2.insertRow(1);
                       var td = tr3.insertCell(0);
                       td.innerHTML = "channel 3";

                   }
           }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code.

- Typo: `documenet.getElementById("t2");`, should be `document.get...`
- There's no need to put the CSS into Javascript
- You create a new table on every `mouseover`, this gives you lots of tables. You shouldn't create the tables dynamically. You can create them before and just populate with the rows. This simplifies your Javascript code and helps reduce the possibilities for bugs

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <table id="t1"></table>
    <table id="t2"></table>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    background: url('http://www.macwallhd.com/wp-content/Wallpapers/Animals/Desktop%20Cats%20As%20Hunters%20Pet%20Pictures10.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
#t1, #t2 {
    background-color:blue;
    color:White;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:0.3;
    margin-top:150px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
}
#t2 {
    margin-left:290px;
    display: none;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    //Table Creation Start
    var table = document.getElementById("t1");
    var tr1 = table.insertRow(0);
    var td = tr1.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "favourites";

    var tr2 = table.insertRow(1);
    var td = tr2.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "system";

    var tr3 = table.insertRow(1);
    var td = tr3.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "settings";

    /***********Table creation End****/

    var table2 = document.createElement("table");
    table2.id = "t2";
    tr1.addEventListener("mouseover", createTable, false);

    tr1.addEventListener("mouseout", removeTable, false);
};

function createTable() {
    var table2 = document.getElementById("t2");
    table2.innerHTML = '';

    var tr1 = table2.insertRow(0);
    var td = tr1.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "channel 1";

    var tr2 = table2.insertRow(1);
    var td = tr2.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "channel 2";

    var tr3 = table2.insertRow(1);
    var td = tr3.insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "channel 3";

    table2.style.display = 'block';
}

function removeTable() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("t2");
    elem.style.display = 'none';
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4bCC/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/pd3a6/)

JS:

```
    function myFunction()
    {
      document.body.style.background = "url('http://www.macwallhd.com/wp-content/Wallpapers/Animals/Desktop%20Cats%20As%20Hunters%20Pet%20Pictures10.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed"
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "wrapper";
      div.style.cssText = "margin-top: 150px;";        // added;

    //Table Creation Start
      var table = document.createElement("table");
      table.id = "t1";
      table.style.cssText = "background-color:blue;color:White; padding:10px; opacity:0.3;display:block; position:absolute;align:center;width:250px;height:300px;";
      div.appendChild(table);

      var tr1 = table.insertRow(0);
      var td = tr1.insertCell(0);
      td.innerHTML = "favourites";

      var tr2 = table.insertRow(1);
      var td = tr2.insertCell(0);
      td.innerHTML = "system";

      var tr3 = table.insertRow(1);
     var td = tr3.insertCell(0);
      td.innerHTML = "settings";

    /***********Table creation End****/

      var table2 = document.createElement("table");
      table2.id = "t2";
      tr1.addEventListener("mouseover", createTable,false);

      tr1.addEventListener("mouseout", removeTable,false);

      document.body.appendChild(div);
    };

    function createTable()
    {
    //switch(choice)
    //{
    //    case: mouseover
    //        case: mouseout
    //}
      var div = document.getElementById("wrapper");

      var table2 = document.createElement("table");
      table2.id = "t2";
      table2.style.cssText = "background-color:blue;color:White; padding:10px; opacity:0.3;align:center;width:250px;height:300px;margin-left:290px;display:block;";
      div.appendChild(table2);

      var tr1 = table2.insertRow(0);
      var td = tr1.insertCell(0);
      td.innerHTML = "channel 1";
      var tr2 = table2.insertRow(1);
      var td = tr2.insertCell(0);
      td.innerHTML = "channel 2";

      var tr3 = table2.insertRow(1);
      var td = tr3.insertCell(0);
      td.innerHTML = "channel 3";
    }

    function removeTable()
   {
      var div = document.getElementById("wrapper");
      var elem = document.getElementById("t2");
      div.removeChild(elem);

    }
```